# Matplotlib bar chart X-axis Labels order

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, data-visualization, seaborn

Is there a way I can rearrange the x-axis of my bar chart so that the ages are listed in order?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Add a sort_index() after value_counts()

```
www['Age'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```